# How can I modify biblatex's \mkcomprange to not compress ranges between 10 and 19?

Tags: biblatex

According to Oxford style, ranges of numbers where the first and last number are between 10 and 19 (inclusive), or are larger numbers ending in digits between 10 and 19, should not be compressed ‘because of the way they are read or spoken’:

30–1 132–6

but

10–11 112–16

I'm using Biblatex's `\mkcomprange` command to make these compressed ranges.  By using `setcounter{mincomprange}{20}`, I can ensure that ‘10–11‘ remains as it is rather than turning into ‘10-1’.  But ‘112–116’ still turns into ‘112–6’ rather than the desired ‘112–16’.  The definition of `\mkcomprange` in biblatex.sty involves complexities that go beyond my limited TeX programming skills, but I was hoping someone might be able to help me tweak it to get this desired result, i.e. for

`\mkcomprange{30-31, 132-136, 10-11, 112-116}`

to expand to

`30–1, 132–6, 10-11, 112-16`.